# Surface had no valid native surface

Tags: android, android-camera

My Application crashes some time and works some time, I was taking pictures continuously and uploading to Amazon s3 Please help regarding, i was stuck with this problem from long time.

My Log, when application crashes:

```
E/Legacy-CameraDevice-JNI: LegacyCameraDevice_nativeGetSurfaceId: Could not retrieve native Surface from surface.
10-06 15:40:34.760 29235-29350/com.example.grobomac.takephotos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2146
    Process: com.example.grobomac.takephotos, PID: 29235
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Surface had no valid native Surface.
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.nativeGetSurfaceId(Native Method)
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.getSurfaceId(LegacyCameraDevice.java:658)
```